# ¿Tabla de muchos a muchos que referencia a una misma tabla?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Necesito crear una relación de muchos a muchos de la tabla usuarios a la misma tabla. Es decir que tenga la relación hacia ella misma. Al intentar meter la relacion con attach de laravel.

```
$usuario_seguido->user_user()->attach($usuario);
```

Este me da este error.

```
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id_seguido' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `user_user` (`user_id`) values (2))'
```

Esta es la relación en el modelo User.

```
 public function user_user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'user_user')->withPivot('user_id','user_id_seguido');;
}
```

Esta es la tabla pivot

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id_seguido');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('user_id_seguido')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrás que declarar explícitamente las llaves foráneas de la tabla pivot.

Cambié el nombre de la relación por uno más descriptivo, así es más fácil de leer para tí y otros programadores.

```
public function seguidos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_user', 'user_id', 'user_id_seguido');
}
```

Y para declarar la relación inversa:

```
public function seguidores()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_user', 'user_id_seguido', 'user_id');
}
```

Luego podrás relacionar los usuarios:

```
$usuario_seguido->seguidores()->attach($usuarioId);
```

Y obtener los resultados:

```
$seguidores = $user->seguidores;

$seguidos = $user->seguidos;
```